# How to mine Bitcoins in Mathematica?

Tags: cryptography

I see that version 11.3 has some blockchain functionalities, so ***is there a way to mine for bitcoins in Mathematica?***

Perhaps someone could provide a tutorial of the APIs to call and computations needed - this would be amazing.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't have an innate built-in function to mine Bitcoins. Implementing an algorithm to do so is no doubt possible, and might be a really fun exercise, but really stands *no* chance at turning a profit (unless you get improbably lucky early on).

Comment: Even if your computer has a gpu? Still be nice to see a working example at least

Comment: The people who mine bitcoins for profit have thousands of GPUs hooked up running low-level specialized algorithms. You can toy with this in Mathematica, but you won't get anywhere near to what is required for true productivity at this point.

Comment: It would certainly be useful only in that it would help one understand how mining works (nothing wrong with that).  But even then I'm afraid it would be a project much too large to fit a QA here.

Comment: Mathematica is not a very fast language. It's not suitable for this task (unless it's implemented in C as a built-in function)

Comment: @user5601 What kind of mathematical problem does a bitcoin mining consists?